# Eulerian or Lagrangian picture in Fluid mechanics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, flow

[Eulerian or Lagrangian picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) in Fluid mechanics? Yes, this is my question which one should i use in fluid mechanics most, and why, which one is more practical?

Comment: Both are used, it depends on application.

Comment: Doing fluid mechanics in Eulerian setting is complicated, and in Lagrangian setting it's even more complicated.