# Transitioning between Lagrangian and Eulerian fluid variables

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, flow

I'm having trouble understanding the motivation between wanting to transition between the two descriptions.

I figure that switching from [Eulerian to Lagrangian fluid variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) is useful if we want to recover a particle's trajectory maybe? Is there any other reason to do so? and then what are we measuring by switching from Lagrangian to Eulerian?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/288847/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the answer, let's quickly revisit the basic concepts behind each formulation.

For some arbitrary continuum material (solid or fluid), we could consider a reference configuration of the material $\mathscr{B_0}$ at some time $t_0$, and associate every point in the material at that configuration with some position coordinate $\mathbf{X}$. We thus label every differential material element in the continuum by its position in the configuration $\mathscr{B_0}$.

We can track the material element labeled $\mathbf{X}$ during the temporal evolution of the system through a mapping that provides the spatial coordinates $\mathbf{x}$ of that material element. This mapping is of the form $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}(\mathbf{X},t)$. This is the basis for the Lagrangian formulation.

We can invert this mapping in principle in order to track which material element $\mathbf{X}$ is occupying some point in space $\mathbf{x}$, leading to a mapping of the form $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x},t)$. This is the basis of the Eulerian formulation.

As a result, the Lagrangian formulation tracks a specific differential material element while the Eulerian formulation tracks a specific differential *spatial* element. We can use the Eulerian formulation to understand how the properties of a flow change with respect to time, while the Lagrangian formulation furnishes methods to understand how elements *in* the flow change over time.

The Lagrangian formulation is useful when describing effects such as [Taylor dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_dispersion) and [viscoelastic fluids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscoelasticity), in both cases because tracking the evolution of elements in the flow provides more information about the relevant physics than describing the flow itself.